# Pyinstaller to pass command line arguments

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am making an executable from hsj.py using pyinstaller.

hsj.py:

```
import sys

file_url = "http://"+str(sys.argv[1])+":5000/fileW"
print(file_url)
x=raw_input()
```

It just prints the complete url formed from the command line arguments passsed to it.

I want to pass the command line arguments in the pyinstaller command itself. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You want to build and run it in the same command?

Comment: My motive is that the script should not run on my system; i.e if after taking arguments file_url becomes a real url for download then it should not download on my system but when I send that executable to somebody and he runs it the download should occur.

Comment: I am sorry.  That does not explain: *"is there a way to call the pyinstaller for hsj.py script as well as pass arguments to the hsj.py script in the same command"*.  Why do both at the same time/script?

Comment: Okay lets consider i want to run and build it. What should i write in the terminal.

Comment: You want to run it, or you want to build it?  This is my question? They are not the same.

Comment: I need both the answers as i am myself confused what will serve my purpose

Comment: Well if you are confused, then ask a question to help resolve the confusion.  See the [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to build it.

Comment: Don't answer here.  Edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the `x=raw_input()`is supposed to do...

BUT I would recommend you using the built-in module *argparse* instead:

```
import argparse

 def main(arg):
     file_url = "http://"+str(sys.argv[1])+":5000/fileW"
     return file_url

 if __name__ == "__main__":

      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

      #"address" as positional argument
      parser.add_argument("adress")
      args = parser.parse_args()

      if args.adress:
           print(main(args.adress))
      else:
           pass
           #OR:
           #print(main("default adress"))
           #OR:
           #print("TypeError: hsj.py missing 1 required positional argument: \"address\"")
```

## Code Explanation

I defined a main function, just to make things more readable if you want to do more than just print a string, that's not necessary.

`if __name__ == "__main__":` makes sure hsj.py is been run as a script and not used as a module for example.

### Some little extra

`parser.add_argument`is "defining" the argument, you could additionally define a little help text that appears when you type in "hsj.py -h" or "--help"

```
parser.add_argument("adress", help="print out file url")
```

or define the type of input you want (a string by default, so not necessary in your case):

```
parser.add_argument("adress", type=int)
```

## short and ookk version:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

#"address" as positional argument
parser.add_argument("adress")
args = parser.parse_args()

print("http://",arg.adress,":5000/fileW")
```